# Maximum area for back yard with given length of its fence

Tags: calculus, optimization

I've encountered this question :

> We have 900 ft of fence and we want to construct a back yard for a
>       100 ft building. If we are using the building as part of the barrier for
>       the yard, what are the dimensions of the yard that gives the maximum
>       area?

I just set up the equation $2a+2b = 900$ and $a = 450 - b$ then substituted into the area and got $-b^2 + 450$. My question is, as this is just the dimensions for the max area, how do I account for the presence of the building?

Comment: Does the yard have to be rectangular, or can it have another shape?

Comment: I don't know, there is a small drawing on the book where both areas are rectangular, but it says nowhere that they have to.

Comment: So you have a total of 1000ft of yard, including the building. Now it's just a matter of figuring out that the square is the one which has the largest areas among rectangles with fixed perimeter. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128825/maximum-area-of-rectangle-with-fixed-perimeter

Comment: I'm sorry I still can't do it, could you provide more details please? :-/

Comment: Ok, I have found the answer to be with the side = 225. But how do I account for the presence of the building?

Comment: Could anyone help?

Comment: You can split into 2 cases, one where the side touching the building is shorter than 100 feet and one where the side touching the building is longer than 100 feet.

Comment: Do you require that the yard be no wider than the building? Exactly as wide as the building? Wider than the building? These will all affect where the fencing is actually used, and will contribute constraints to the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum area for yard and integrated building](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472007/maximum-area-for-yard-and-integrated-building)

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud Are you interested in my answer or should I delete it ? Any reaction is appreciated.

Comment: Do. Not. Reask. The same question. Ever. Again. Improve the first version instead. This rule is strictly enforced. Because this version has an answer, I will close, merge, and delete the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Edit 1 : forgot a $b$ in both area formula

Edit 2 : finding maximum area

Since your building is part of the barrier, there wont be any fence on it.

Suppose the building is larger than the field.  If side $a$ is on the building, your fisrt equation become $a + 2b = 900$ with $a \leq 100$.  Then $a=900-2b$ and area is $-2b^2 + 900b$.

Derivative is $-4b+900$ which is 0 if $b = 225$.  This value of $b$ gives $a = 450$, this is not in the domain.  The biggest area is obtain when the field is as large as the building, $a=100$ and $b = 400$, so 40 000 square feet.

If the field is larger than the building, the exceeding length will appear in your equation $a+(a-100)+2b=900$, with $100 \leq a \leq 500$. $a = 500-b$ and the area is $-b^2+500b$.

Derivative is $-2b+500$ which is 0 if $b=250$.  This give $a = 250$, it is in the domain.  The area is 62 500 square feet.

Comment: And then what would be the maximum dimensions?

Comment: I'll complete the solution